# There should be only one owner party for an activity in CRM 2011 plug-in

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online

I'm have written a Post-create plug-in to assign a case to team when associated case action record has created. Below is the piece of code:

```
    Entity caseActionEntity = context.InputParameters["Target"];

    EntityReference team = (EntityReference)caseActionEntity.Attributes["fmc_teamid"];
    EntityReference caseEntity = (EntityReference)caseActionEntity.Attributes["regardingobjectid"];

    AssignRequest request = new AssignRequest
    {
          Assignee = new EntityReference("team", team.Id),
          Target = new EntityReference("incident",caseEntity.Id),
    };
    service.Execute(request);
```

But its giving exception as **There should be only one owner party for an activity.** after **service.Execute(request);** executed. Can any one tell me how to assign existing case record to team..?

Answer (score 0):

For reassignment during create simply set the ownerid in pre-create. The code you have will work fine for update.

The post here explains this in detail

[Assign new owner to appointment. "There should be only one owner party for an activity"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173482/crm-2011-assign-new-owner-to-appointment-there-should-be-only-one-owner-part)

Comment: This plug-in is triggering on create of X-Entity record and set the owner of Y-Entity record to the team present in X-Entity record. I guess it doesn't matter whether its pre-create or post-create or update. And I also tried the link what u given here..

Comment: Apologize. I misunderstood the problem. Is this a new CRM enironment or was it upgraded from a previous version.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I was thinking along the same lines as Vishnu's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10346623/654495), but the case already exists as you've stated.

The only other thing I can suggest is see how you go by making it an Async plugin so it happens outside the executing transaction.